# Filament PHP - Complex calculated column not showing correctly in custom view

Tags: laravel-filament, filamentphp

I have a form in which I have 3 numeric fields, like this:

```
TextInput::make('number_adults')->label('Adults')
    ->live()
    ->numeric()
    ->afterStateUpdated(function (Get $get, Set $set) {
        self::calculateTransferPrices($get, $set);
    }),
TextInput::make('number_children')->label('Children')
    ->live()
    ->numeric()
    ->afterStateUpdated(function (Get $get, Set $set) {
        self::calculateTransferPrices($get, $set);
    }),
TextInput::make('number_infants')->label('Infants')
    ->live()
    ->numeric()
    ->afterStateUpdated(function (Get $get, Set $set) {
        self::calculateTransferPrices($get, $set);
    }),
```

The `calculateTransferPrices` function performs some calculation based on the form fields, and other data inside the livewire component. The function updates some public fields on the livewire component `$totalShuttle` and `$totalPrivate`. **The calculation is performed correctly, based on debugging the function. The values of the 2 public fields are also correct.**

I use a view field to display the 2 calculated values.

The problem is that the view field does not display the values correctly, every time I update one of the 3 numeric fields, the value displayed is for the old value. Like if the value was supposed to be 100 for each adult, when the adult field gets to 2, the value displayed is 100, and if the adults == 3, the value is 200.

I think that somehow the component is not refreshed, but cannot make it past that assumption. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: please show your *calculateTransferPrices()*

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem as you, what worked for me was to add a debounce to the live like so:

```php
->live(debounce: 500)
```

Also, we don't know if your `calculateTransferPrices()` is getting and setting the right thing.

Anyway, hope you fixed your issue and if you did it would be cool if you post it here.